# Recursive directory searcer PHP

Tags: php, oop, recursion

How can i write an recursice directory searcher that takes a geven string and return the whole path plus the filename in php?

Comment: Does it have to be OOP? If not use `glob` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). It returns an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The php function `dir` will help you.

**http://php.net/manual/en/class.dir.php**

There is an example in the notes of the docs (by sojka at online-forum dot net) that shows doing this, which I have included below...

```
<?php
public static function getTreeFolders($sRootPath = UPLOAD_PATH_PROJECT, $iDepth = 0) {
      $iDepth++;
      $aDirs = array();
      $oDir = dir($sRootPath);
      while(($sDir = $oDir->read()) !== false) {
        if($sDir != '.' && $sDir != '..' && is_dir($sRootPath.$sDir)) {
          $aDirs[$iDepth]['sName'][] = $sDir;
          $aDirs[$iDepth]['aSub'][]  = self::getTreeFolders($sRootPath.$sDir.'/',$iDepth);
        }
      }
      $oDir->close();
      return empty($aDirs) ? false : $aDirs;
}
?>
```

There are lots of other similar examples from other people on the same page, so find one that you like and go from there...

Comment: but that doesnt take an filename as args like getTreeFolders($filename,$path)

Comment: There are lots of examples on the link I provided that perform lots of different recursive searches of a directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate trough the dirctory using a RecursiveDirectoryIterator.
Look at this:

```
$search_query = "test";
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/path/');
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
$result = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/^.+\'.$search_query.'$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
```

Then `(array) $result` should usually contain all filenames in which 'test' was found under '/path/'.

Hope it helps ;)